# Dynamically include header and footer on every page without server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, footer

I'm developing a web application and want to keep the client strictly HTML/JS/CSS with no server side generated HTML.

The servlet container is Tomcat serving up a REST API to the client using stateless authentication.  This will make scaling in the future a lot easier without worrying about sticky sessions or managing sessions in some external store.

My issue at the moment is I'm using JQuery to dynamically insert a header.html and footer.html on page load.  As expected there is a delay before the header and footer appear.

Apart from statically putting the HTML in each page of the website, what would people recommend as options?

Comment: For what reason do you not want to use server side includes? They solve the problem you have of the FOUC, as well as reduce the three requests you're making to the server to a single one.

Comment: make the page wait until the jQuery has loaded, could try looking into holdReady(); see if that will help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I'm actually considering something basic like PHP but I'd like the web servers that end up serving the HTML to be as light as possible with all the grunt work being performed by the app servers.  Is there anything that exists that can generate your build ready HTML with included header and footer but just write once?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single page appliction, so the header and footer stays the same, only the body changes content.

Something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/ArnoutPullen/0egv7rdL/1/

index.html:

```
<header>
  Header
  <li class="customers" title="Customers">Customers</li>
  <li class="companies" title="Companies">Companies</li>
</header>
<div class="body">Body</div>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function(){
    $(".body").html($(this).attr('title'));
    //$(".body").load('customers.html');
  });  
});
```

customers.html

```
customers
```

Comment: Ah I see where you're going with that but I'm not sure it would work in my case. I would need people to be able to link to 'customer.html' which in your case would provide a page with no headers and footers because they are only loaded from index.html.

Comment: @jimmy in that case you could just work with your DNS redirects and redirect all requests to the index.html and let index.html handle that request of url, that's the idea of single page apps.